# Coding a button used to get counts based on radio button selections

Tags: vb.net, radio-button

I am working on an a visual basic app that connects to a microsoft access db called Trips.  It keeps track of business and pleasure trips for a person.  The user should be able to display the total number of business and pleasure trips, all trips and number of trips from a specific origin to a specific destination.  The last part is where I am running in to trouble.  When I click btn_Trips  after making my radio button selections its pulling all rows with either the selected origin or selected destination instead of pulling the rows that only contain that specific origin and destination and then displaying the count.  I am not sure how to go about fixing this so any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off

Public Class frmMain

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'TripsDataSet.tblTrips' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.TblTripsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TripsDataSet.tblTrips)
End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAll.Click
    'displays all trips
    Me.TblTripsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TripsDataSet.tblTrips)
    TblTripsDataGridView.DataSource = TripsDataSet.tblTrips
End Sub


Private Sub btnCount_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCount.Click
    'displays either business trips or pleasure trips
    Dim foundRows() As TripsDataSet.tblTripsRow
    Dim businesspleasure As String = ""
    If radBusiness.Checked Then
        businesspleasure = "B"
    ElseIf radPleasure.Checked Then
        businesspleasure = "P"
    End If

    foundRows = CType(Me.TripsDataSet.tblTrips.Select("BusinessPleasure = '" & businesspleasure & "'"), Trips_Project.TripsDataSet.tblTripsRow())

    Dim ds As New TripsDataSet.tblTripsDataTable
    For Each row As DataRow In foundRows
        ds.ImportRow(row)
    Next
    TblTripsDataGridView.DataSource = ds

    MessageBox.Show("Trips:  " & TblTripsDataGridView.RowCount - 1)
End Sub

Private Sub btnTrips_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTrips.Click
    Dim foundOrigin() As TripsDataSet.tblTripsRow
    Dim foundDestin() As TripsDataSet.tblTripsRow
    Dim originTrip As String
    Dim destinTrip As String

    If radOrAtl.Checked Then
        originTrip = "Atlanta"
    ElseIf radOrChi.Checked Then
        originTrip = "Chicago"
    ElseIf radOrLa.Checked Then
        originTrip = "Los Angeles"
    Else
        originTrip = "Nashville"
    End If
    foundOrigin = CType(Me.TripsDataSet.tblTrips.Select("Origin = '" & originTrip & "'"), Trips_Project.TripsDataSet.tblTripsRow())

    If radDestAtl.Checked Then
        destinTrip = "Atlanta"
    ElseIf radDestChi.Checked Then
        destinTrip = "Chicago"
    ElseIf radDestLa.Checked Then
        destinTrip = "Los Angeles"
    Else
        destinTrip = "Nashville"
    End If
    foundDestin = CType(Me.TripsDataSet.tblTrips.Select("Destination = '" & destinTrip & "'"), Trips_Project.TripsDataSet.tblTripsRow())

    Dim ds As New TripsDataSet.tblTripsDataTable
    For Each row As DataRow In foundOrigin
        ds.ImportRow(row)
    Next
    For Each row As DataRow In foundDestin
        ds.ImportRow(row)
    Next
    TblTripsDataGridView.DataSource = ds

    MessageBox.Show("Total Trips:  " & TblTripsDataGridView.RowCount - 1)
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
....
foundOrigin = CType(Me.TripsDataSet.tblTrips.Select("Origin = '" & originTrip & "'"), Trips_Project.TripsDataSet.tblTripsRow())

....
foundDestin = CType(Me.TripsDataSet.tblTrips.Select("Destination = '" & destinTrip & "'"), Trips_Project.TripsDataSet.tblTripsRow())
```

You're selecting trips with the selected origin on one array, and trips with the selected destination on another array. You can use `AND` to select both in one sentence:

```
If radOrAtl.Checked Then
    originTrip = "Atlanta"
ElseIf radOrChi.Checked Then
    originTrip = "Chicago"
ElseIf radOrLa.Checked Then
    originTrip = "Los Angeles"
Else
    originTrip = "Nashville"
End If

If radDestAtl.Checked Then
    destinTrip = "Atlanta"
ElseIf radDestChi.Checked Then
    destinTrip = "Chicago"
ElseIf radDestLa.Checked Then
    destinTrip = "Los Angeles"
Else
    destinTrip = "Nashville"
End If
foundTrips = CType(Me.TripsDataSet.tblTrips.Select(String.Format("Origin = '{0}' AND Destination = '{1}'", originTrip, destinTrip)), Trips_Project.TripsDataSet.tblTripsRow())
```

I also suggest using `String.Format` when concatening more than one string.

Another option is LINQ as stated in another answer, but IMO is an overkill because this is a simple case and because datatable already gives you a flexible method to filter rows.

Comment: Thanks, I tried making the changes but its still not working right for me.  Any other suggestions or help?  I am ready to pull my hair out!

Comment: I must have had a typo!  I re-entered my code and its working now!  I greatly appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Linq and the different methods you can use. I don't know exactly what you want to end up with, but if I've interpreted your explanation correctly you just want the count of these rows. You should be able to use linq (see [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386910(v=vs.110).aspx)) with datatables, so:

```
Dim query =
    from row in Me.TripsDataSet.tblTripsDataTable
    where row.Origin = originTrip and row.Destination = destinTrip
    select row

MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Total Trips: {0}", query.Count())
```